# Backbone Marrionete binding issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, marionette

On my UI I have:

```
<div class='large-12 columns'>
  <div id="gritslider"></div>
  <input rows="3" id='grit' placeholder='Please enter' type='text' />
</div>
```

In Code I have:

```
onShow: function () {

        $( "#gritslider" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            values: [ 75, 300 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#grit" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            }
        });
    },
```

Slider works just fine, it shows on the scree. But when I save, the value that is located in the input field (the same value set by jqueryui) is not picked up and saved.
Lets say I set value 10-100 using slider, and if I focus in textbox and change it manualy (change first one to 2) then it gets saved.

What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solutions to my issue that works, but it feels like a hack in a way. It is true that I use set function provided by Backbone, but I was hoping binding would work out of the box... in any case, solution to my particular problem:

```
onShow: function () {
        var that = this;
        $( "#gritslider" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            values: [ 75, 300 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                debugger;
                that.model.set("grit", ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] )
                $( "#grit" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
                that.bindings.grit = "#grit";
                $("#grit").focus();
            }
        });
    },
```